# Primefaces 8 ajax status not hiding after p:dataTable pagination

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a lazy loaded primefaces 8 datatable as follows:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{....model}" var="..." rows="20" lazy="true"
                                     paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                     currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord}-{endRecord} of {totalRecords} records"
                                     emptyMessage="No records found">
....
</p:dataTable>
```

and a p:ajaxStatus defined as follows:

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()"/>
    <p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="false" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false"
              showHeader="false"
              styleClass="app-loader-dialog">
        <div id="app-loader" class="app-loader">
            <div class="app-loader-content">
                loading...
            </div>
        </div>
    </p:dialog>
```

The issue I noticed is that when paginating, the status dialog opens, but it stays open even after the pagination is complete, at which it is expected to hide.

But for other ajax activities such as dependent dropdown, etc. it shows and hides appropriately.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Any errors in your browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: Hi @JasperdeVries, thanks. I dont get an error but this warning in the console: `Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/`

Comment: how about using `oncomplete` instead of `onsuccess` ?  I do exactly what you are doing but I use `oncomplete`.

Comment: Hi @Melloware, thanks. I have tried this and still same issue.

Comment: Hi @Melloware , its working now. was my mistake, I had to wrap the dataTable in a h:form and its working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrapped the dataTable in a h:form, and its working now.